# line break in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm having a problem with UILabel in xCode.

These cell is ok:

[image]

But when I scroll down and then scroll up I have this:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

I think that the problem is because i have sizeToFit in the cell but If I don't put the text will appear in the middle

Comment: What settings do you have on the cells?  What do your datasource methods look like?  Are these custom cells or default `UITableViewCell` cells?

Comment: Not going to post this as an answer because it isn't a good one. I noticed this as well, but it wasn't really for anything important, so I fixed it pretty lazily. I just manually defined the frame of the label instead of using an kind of constraint and it was fixed.

Comment: Ahh the annoying cell layout issues! Do you perhaps use `prepareForReuse` and forgot to call the super implementation?

Comment: I put sizeToFit on the cell...I think this is the problem but why? If I don't put sizeToFit the text will appear in the middle

Comment: Is custom cell but have nothing in special

Comment: You should size all your elements in `layoutSubviews`, after calling the super implementation.

Comment: `sizeToFit` is definitely the problem. It keeps the current width and gives the needed height.

Comment: I don't know how I do this